# Make Products Non-Visible

Tags: product, adminhtml

I am in need of how to make the products not visible within the front end of the system but still be able to place an order against them. I want to make all of them not visible within the customer front end portal.

i.e. I cannot disable the product because it will not let me place an order against them when they have a status of disabled

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can just change the **Visbility** of your products to **Not visible individually** and that'll do the trick ;)

Take note that it is something you can do for all the products via the mass action attributes update of the Catalog Product Grid of the backend.

Comment: They are already set as that and they still show up in the product catalog...

Comment: @user40282 flush your cache, they should not show up if the visbility is set to not visible

Comment: flush the entire magento cache?

Comment: @user40282 yes give it a try

Comment: that did not work either. we are running an outdated version so I am wondering if that is the case.